# Navigation Bar Mobile Size Issue

Tags: css

I got a navigation bar on my blog it works fine except when I see the website from my iPhone 7 plus , which is 750px it doesn't show correctly, Basiclly the nav bar displays desktop size on mobile devices also on other devices such as ipad etc.. I tried to use @media quray but it didn't work.

**For example for the iphone I did this but it didn't work**

```
@media screen and (max-width:750px){ #MBL_wrapper
{
width: 40%;
margin: auto;
top:-2px;
background: #16132b;
height: 50px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #D2D2D3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d2d2d3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d2d2d3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #D2D2D3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
border-left: 10px solid #f00;
border-right: 10px solid #f00;
}}
```

```
**my Nav bar code is :**
/*--MyBloggerLab Sticky Navigation Bar--*/
#MBL_wrapper .MBL_social_wrapper
{
margin-top: 15px;
        position: absolute;
    left: 600px;
}

#MBL_wrapper
{
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
top:-2px;
background: #16132b;
height: 50px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #D2D2D3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d2d2d3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d2d2d3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #D2D2D3, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
border-left: 10px solid #f00;
border-right: 10px solid #f00;
}

#MBL_wrapper .topmenu.notice
{
float: left;
width: 500px;
margin-top: 15px;
color: #fff;
}

#top_menu a
{
color: #fff;
}

#top_menu
{
display: block;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin-top: 12px;
}

#top_menu li
{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 15px;
font-family: &#39;Patua One&#39;, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#top_menu li ul
{

}

#boxed_wrapper
{
width: 980px;
margin: auto;
}

.MBL_standard_wrapper
{
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
}

.MBL_standard_wrapper.wide
{
width: 980px;
}

.MBL_standard_wrapper.header
{
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.MBL_social_wrapper
{
width: auto;
float: right;
}

#menuforall .MBL_social_wrapper
{
margin-top: 15px;
}

.MBL_social_wrapper ul
{
list-style: none;
}

.MBL_social_wrapper ul li
{
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.MBL_social_wrapper ul li img
{
width: 24px;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper
{
width: 930px;
height: 50px;
padding: 0;
margin:auto;
}

.mainmenu.notice
{
float: left;
width: 600px;
padding: 17px 0 10px 12px;
z-index: 999;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav
{
list-style: none;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 23px 0 5px;
width: 700px;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav li
{
display: block;
float :left;
margin: 0;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul, #MBL_menu_wrapper div .nav li ul, .main_nav li ul
{
display: none;
list-style: none;
background: #000;
position:absolute;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 51px;
width: 200px;
height: auto;
z-index: 1000;
padding-top: 5px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
border-left: 0;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul li ul, #MBL_menu_wrapper div .nav li ul, .main_nav li ul li ul
{
margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav li ul li a, .nav li ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li.current_page_parent ul.sub-menu li.current_page_item a, .nav li.current-menu-parent ul.sub-menu li.current_page_item a
{
background: none;
}

.main_nav li ul li
{
width: 100%;
}

#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav li ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav li.current-menu-item ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav li ul li.current-menu-item a,#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li.current-menu-item ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul li.current-menu-item a
{
color: #fff;
display: block;
width: 188px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1em;
padding: 10px 0 10px 12px;
background: none;
}

.main_nav ul, .main_nav
{
list-style: none;
margin: auto;
width: 600px;
height: 50px;
z-index: 999;
float: left;

}

.main_nav ul li,  .main_nav li
{
display: block;
float :left;
margin: 0;
}

.main_nav ul li a,  .main_nav li a
{
display: block;
float :left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 18px 15px 14px 15px;
color: #fff;
font-family: &#39;Patua One&#39;;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 500;
}

.main_nav ul li ul li a,  .main_nav li ul li a
{
width: 165px;
padding: 7px 19px 7px 16px;
border: 0;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ccc;
font-family: &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Helvetica, Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

.main_nav ul li ul li:last-child a,  .main_nav li ul li:last-child a
{
border-bottom: 0;
}

.main_nav ul li a:hover,  .main_nav li a:hover, .main_nav ul li a.hover,  .main_nav li a.hover, .main_nav ul li a:active,  .main_nav li a:active, .main_nav li.current-menu-item a
{
color: #fff;
background: #830000;
}

.main_nav li:last-child a:hover, .main_nav li:last-child a.hover
{
border-right: 0;
}

.main_nav li ul li a,  .main_nav li.current-menu-item ul li a,#MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li.current-menu-item ul li a, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul li.current-menu-item a,
{
display: block;
width: 170px;
line-height: 0.7em;
padding: 5px 0 5px 30px;
}

.main_nav li ul li a:hover,  .main_nav li.current-menu-item ul li a:hover, .main_nav li ul li a.hover,  .main_nav li.current-menu-item ul li a.hover, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li.current-menu-item ul li a:hover, #MBL_menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul li.current-menu-item a:hover, .main_nav li ul li:last-child a:hover, .main_nav li ul li:last-child a.hover
}

 div
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
font-weight:inherit;
font-style:inherit;
font-size:100%;
font-family:inherit;
vertical-align:baseline;
}

a
{
color: #2C2F32;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: color .2s linear, background .1s linear;
-moz-transition: color .2s linear, background .1s linear;
-ms-transition: color .2s linear, background .1s linear;
-o-transition: color .2s linear, background .1s linear;
transition: color .2s linear, background .1s linear;
}
```

[my blog] bit.ly/3b2z5zJ

- HTML

```
 <!-- Begin Navigation -->
<div id='MBL_wrapper'>
<div class='MBL_standard_wrapper'>
<div class='menu-main-menu-container'><ul class='main_nav' id='main_menu'><li class='menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-533' id='menu-item-533'>

<a href=''>Home</a></li>
<li><a href=''>Downloads</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>About Us</a></li>
  
  <div class='dropdown'>
  <li><a href='#'>More</a></li>
  <div class='dropdown-child'> 
    <a href=''/>
    <a href=''>Services</a>
    <a href=''>FAQ</a>
    <a href=''>Contact Us</a>
    <a href=''>Support Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
</ul></div>
```

```
-Dropdown

.dropdown {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-child {
    display: none;
    background-color: #16132b;
    min-width: 50px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
   
}
.dropdown-child a {
    padding: 3px;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: &#39;Changa&#39;;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 60px;

     
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-child {
    display: block;

   
   
}
    
.dropdown-child  a:hover {background-color: #830000;}
```

Please note there is a social media wrapper too that I need to hide  on mobile its in the first CSS code above

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your HTML code and your CSS?

Comment: Worth noting that the scroll bar on the site is awfully sized and you're better using the OS one.

Comment: @RaheelJunaid I added the html

Comment: @learningtoanimate how can I use OS

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation bar seems to be set up in an odd fashion. I would suggest doing it like this so it's as responsive and simple as possible.

```css
/* Resets */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #16132b;
  border-left: 5px red solid;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: maroon;
}


/* Flex Boxes */

.main-links {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* JS Needed */

.dropdown ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div class="main-links">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="">Dropdown</a></li>
      <ul>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href="">Services</a>
        <a href="">FAQ</a>
        <a href="">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="">Support Us</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This navigation bar has a fixed with so it won't get the "shrinking" effect that your navbar has. This also keeps your code clean by using the semantic `<nav>` tag instead of tons of classes. There are no Media Queries as a simple navigation bar such as this doesn't require any (I shrank the viewport to test this). You may customize the breakpoints using media queries if you wish.

### Changes I made

- Kept the CSS readable
- Removed unnecessary classes
- Simplified dropdown using tag selectors
- Used CSS `flexbox` instead of the mostly obsolete `float` property
- Removed padding and margin redundancies (`margin: 0;` instead of `margin: 0 0 0 0;`)
- Removed `display` properties where they weren't applicable

These are general pointers when working with CSS. Please do keep your code simple, as well as the code in future Stack Overflow questions (see [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to ensure that it's easier for members of the community to assist you; this is the reason I couldn't modify your current CSS.

Comment: thank you for your time and effort I really appreciate it however it didn't work, see the image https://i.imgur.com/fsjTmlR.png , also I added my dropdown CSS on top , sorry I forgot to add it

Comment: If you view the code snippet, it does work. I said that you may customize it however you choose on your own site. Looking at your image, it seems your implementation is incorrect: Your social media buttons are in the wrong place, your links are overlapping, etc. CSS Tricks has a good [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you'd like to check it out. I also noticed that the screenshot you provided was on the desktop viewport, not on mobile (which is where you were having your issue).